# Github & Git bash: How can I bring changes from online repository to my local repository through Git bash?

Tags: git, bash, github, git-bash

I want to bring changes updated in online repository to my local repository. Here is what I have done:

I have a project and I've uploaded it on Git repository named as `Android-app`.

1. I've done some work on this project at my office and uploaded changes on GitHub.
2. I've reached my home and I've already cloned that repository (`Android-app`) to my laptop earlier.

Now, what I want is to bring online changes to my current repository on laptop without cloning again. How can I do that with Git bash?

Comment: `git fetch`, `git rebase`. Time to [RT*M](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes), perhaps?

Comment: ^ those and `git pull`. I’m surprised you managed to push your changes to your repository if you don’t know how to interact with remotes.

Comment: telling any beginner to use ``git pull`` is asking for trouble

Comment: Yeah @ Sébastien Dawans..You've got me right..I am a beginner..:-)

Comment: @poke I had some idea about how to clone, connect to remote, upload you current changes to Remote etc. but i didn't have the idea of the  asked question..but You guys are just Awesome to help out..:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple command to do this job: The command is :

```
git pull
```

or

```
git pull origin master
```

In the second command master is your branch name and origin is the remote name, place the branch name in which you are working instead of master. If you want pull changes from the current branch then first command is pretty enough.

Comment: `git fetch origin` and then `git pull` on your branches should do the same. Git fetch updates your repository head and Git pull fetches changes to your repository branch.

Comment: Thanks @Imran and Lars Nielsen..That really helped me a lot !!